# Number of changes in adjacent symbol in a binary message

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance, expected-value

A message is sent over a communication channel. The message is made up of $n$ symbols, each of which may be $0$ and $1$. Each is equiprobable and independent of the other. Find the expectation and variance of the random variable $X$ which corresponds to the number of changes in the symbols (for example, if $0101$ is the message, the number of changes is $3$ in the message.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Right now, it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Find expectation of an indicator random variable $X_i$, which takes the value $1$ if change in symbols occurs between $i^{th}$ to $(i+1)^{th}$, and $0$ otherwise. This is just the probability of a change of symbol from $i^{th}$ to $(i+1)^{th}$ index, which is easy to calculate.

Then use $X = \sum X_i$ and linearity of expectation to get $E(X)$.